# Python project deployment on Ubuntu 18 server

Tags: python, ubuntu, deployment, path

Ive created my simple script (tg bot), but after uploading on my Ubuntu server (python in alternative mode ==3.9.13, pip freeze and installed requirements). There is some path (I suppose) problem:

```
root@tele:/# python3 /root/mybot/workDir/coreFiles/coreBot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/mybot/workDir/coreFiles/coreBot.py", line 6, in <module>
    from workDir.sets import config
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'workDir'
```

In my core file there is some imports:

```
from workDir.sets import config
from workDir.methods.states.comdsHandler import getHandler
```

Here is my project tree:

```
workDir/
    ├─coreFiles/
    │ └─coreBot.py
    ├─methods/
    │ ├─states/
    │ │ ├─actionStates.py
    │ │ └─comdsHandler.py
    │ └─utils/
    │   ├─connectionDB.py
    │   ├─loggingUtil.py
    │   ├─registerUserInDB.py
    │   └─strParser.py
    └─sets/
      ├─categories.py
      └─config.py
```

Kindly help find better solution than make it in one py file :)

Comment: do you have \_\_init\_\_.py file in workDir ?  in addition, try to create a simple main.py file in workDir and see if you can import  `from workDir.sets import config` from it

Comment: There is no `__init__.py` file in workDir, because it only folder. Do I need it?

main py works: `root@tele:~# python3 /root/mybot/workDir/main.py
>Hi`

But the main problem still exist

Comment: so, you haven't packaged and installed this project? that would be the typical solution here.

Answer (score 1):

There is a couple issues. You are handling folders as if they are python files and you may be getting confused in the folder structure. To clarify:

`import X from Y` --> would return X (which could be a class or function or whatever) within the file `Y.py`

Hence, in your case you want to just:

```
import workDir.sets.config
```

As you aren't loading anything specific from `config.py`, you just want the whole file.

Additionally, the import structure is heavily dependent on where your working directory for the script you are running is within. Is the script you are running inside workDir? If so, you don't need to put `import workDir.sets.config` `import .sets.config` should suffice.

If you don't know the directory run `print(os.getcwd())`

EDIT:
I noticed you are loading from `/workDir/coreFiles/coreBot.py`, is this correct?
If so, you need to load a file from a parent directory:

```
import ..sets.config
```

Comment: "Additionally, the import structure is heavily dependent on where your working directory for the script you are running is within" it **shouldn't be**